# css override ULTIMO theme for Magefan BLOG - magento 2.2.1

Tags: css, magento, themes, overriding, blogs

In my www.salamitaly.com with magento 2.2.1 I have installed BLOG from MAGEFAN and insert a widget to show "recent Posts List" into home page

But I get an odd visualization (you can have a look on salamitaly.com currently on line or at the attached screenshot) I mean the 3 posts have different height and those are not in line but the third one end up in a new line below the first two

I guess I need to override file from blog extension

```
public_html/app/code/Magefan/Blog/view/frontend/web/css/blog-custom.css
```

In my theme, copying it into folder

```
public_html/app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/web/css/blog-custom.css
```

but don't know exactly the CSS I need to insert into the **blog-custom.css**  file

Could anybody help on that 
suggesting the CSS code snippet?

[post list screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDdpo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I find out solution

files to update is public_html/app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/web/css_custom.less

adding following snippet

```css
.blog-widget-recent .post-holder {
    width: 28%;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```